# Grails data binding with child causes index out of bounds

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a structure with the following domain classes:

```
class Service{ static hasMany=[serviceRequirements:ServiceRequirement]}
```

And of course a bunch of member variables... 
Problem occurs when I'm trying to set the properties in the controller like this:

```
service.properties = params
```

I get the following error:

```
Executing action [update] of controller [se.hb.eme.DeveloperController] caused exception: Invalid property 'serviceRequirements[0]' of bean class [se.hb.eme.Service]: Index of out of bounds in property path 'serviceRequirements[0]'; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

There's pretty much no documentation on grails.org about this and I really can't figure out the problem...

The .gsp is pretty simple. (I removed some fields...)

```
<g:form action="create">
<g:textField name="header" />
<g:textField name="serviceRequirements[0].header" /> 
<g:submitButton value="Create" />
```

Comment: The default Collection type is Set for hasMany and Set's don't have indexed properties.  You would need to add List serviceRequirements = [] to your domain for your GSP syntax to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly that's because the code is trying to set element 0 of a list, which has no elements in it, thus throwing an index out of bounds exception.

Try this in your domain class:

```
class Service{
  List<ServiceRequirement> serviceRequirements = ListUtils.lazyList(new ArrayList(), {new ServiceRequirement()} as org.apache.commons.collections.Factory)
  static hasMany = [serviceRequirements:ServiceRequirement]
}
```